Set Cookie of API Headers Response in browser cookies in App router in nextjs 14
I am trying to set the cookies in the browser Application. I get the cookies values from the response of the API's headers as set-cookie. This is the value:
'set-cookie': 'sessionid=<REDACTED>; expires=Sun, 22 Nov 2025 04:02:33 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/, expires=Sat, 04 Nov 2024 04:02:33 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=5453453; Path=/',

Here is the page calling the API on the server side.
import { getMainData } from "@/api/server";

export default async function Home() {
  const response = await getMainData();

  return (
    <div>
      Home Data
    </div>
  );
}

This is the API function.
import { BASE_URL } from "@/lib/constants";
export async function getMainData() {
  try {
    const _res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/main/data/`, {
      method: "GET",
      credentials: "include",
      mode: "cors",
    });

    console.log("_res", _res);

    const _data = await _res.json();

    return {
      response: _data,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      response: error,
    };
  }
}

Kindly give the solution to set the cookies in the browser.

you can import cookie like this
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

and after that you should use set method from cookie which you have imported from next/headers like this :
cookies().set('name of token', yourtoken ,  { httpOnly: true })

and then return your token
